# Runtime error 1004 Application defined or object defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting a Runtime error 1004 and when I debug it, it takes me to this sub, this sub works fine in another sheet, I don't know whats wrong, can anyone help??

```
Public Sub allowEdit()
  Me.Unprotect PASSWORD
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Me.Columns(HIDDEN_DATA_RANGE).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Replace Me with ActiveSheet

Comment: Or better use ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("SheetName")

Comment: Which line actually causes the error? Also, where and how is `PASSWORD` declared?
 If the sub is in a worksheet module, then `Me` is correct.

Comment: I tried using thisWorkbook, it gives a type mismatch error 13.

Comment: Public Sub allowEdit()
ActiveSheet.Unprotect PASSWORD
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.Columns(HIDDEN_DATA_RANGE).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
 
End Sub   this gives me the same error 1004

Comment: Private Const PASSWORD = "dmsprlock"  this is defined at the top of the sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("SheetName")
```

Did the trick.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).